# Using directive for package added in Visual Studio Code

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying trying to build a web app with ASP.NET Core 3.0 and using VS Code to do it. Moreover, I'm using MySQL for my database, and this is where things are getting rough. It seems like there's very little support out there for this particular combination of VS Code and MySQL.

I can't find any tutorials with this particular combination, so I can't figure out how to put it all together. I ran the `dotnet add package Mysql` command, which installed the package, and I see that it's been added to the .csproj file, **except now I don't know how to make use of it in my Model file**. I'm trying to find the `using` directive for it, but I can't find any posts on any forums addressing this issue.

Comment: Check the docs [Creating a model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/). It's same for every EF Core provider, only difference is in your Startup classes `ConfigureServices` on the AddDbContext call and `UseXxx` (instead of `UseSqlServer`)

Comment: Ok, I checked the docs. Now I've got the Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql package installed and the using directive works fine. I'll be deciphering the remainder of your comment in the coming hours. Thank you good sir.

Comment: And now I've got everything set up in ```ConfigureServices```! Thanks again!